# kafka-node npm install failing on windows 7

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to apache kafka and trying to install their node client which is failing with the following message-
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.4.1, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.

Comment: Your `python --version` is obiously 3.4.1. Do you have any other python installed?

Comment: didn't work with python2.7 as well....got stuck at some Visual C== error!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's an optional dependency called snappy that requires compilation. This dependency has been made optional since kafka-node v0.3.3 and above  so you can ignore any errors generated from `npm install`.